# Internationalized Routing in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization, url-routing

How can Nextjs detect the user's country and plug it into the URL
if it helps we have the user's country in the cookies through Cloudflare, but we want our site to be personalized for a couple of countries.
Nextjs docs suggested the following

```
i18n: {
    locales: ['en-US', 'fr', 'nl-NL'],
    defaultLocale: 'en-US', 
}
```

In my case, I don't want to manually plug all of the countries in both en and ar. Is there a way to detect it and change the URL accordingly or do you suggest plugging the countries we are interested in and having a default one for the rest of the world?
I don't want to create common.json file for each one, for example, en-US and en-UK I want to have these as sub paths in my URL but I want them both to read from en/common.json

Comment: _"do you suggest plugging the countries we are interested in and having a default one for the rest of the world"_ - That's what I'd suggest you should do.

Comment: @juliomalves yeah but I don't want to create common.json file for each one, for example, en-US and en-UK I want to have these as sub paths in my URL but I want them both to read from en/common.json can this be done?

Comment: @juliomalves any suggestion on how can this be configured in my i18n.js and next.config.js? if yes please post it as an answer

Comment: NextJS has a middleware feature that might help (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware). If not maybe setting some re-write rules (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites)

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the [next-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next) library. They do a really good job on documenting common use cases. As for your specific question, you can set the locale of the Next.js router in next-i18next by using the following code:

```
const { i18n } = useTranslation();

// These are mock locales, you can get those from your Cookie
const localeOptions = [
  { language: 'en', code: 'USA' },
  { language: 'es', code: 'ESP' },
];

const changeLanguage = (language: string) => {
  i18n.changeLanguage(language);
  router.push(`/${language}${router.asPath}`, `/${language}${router.asPath}`, { locale: language });
};
```

Do let me know if you've got any more questions!

Comment: what I want is to have language en valid for different codes example en-US code and en-UK code should be in my URL but both will give english language

Answer (score 0):

next js make auto-detection by the browser you can stop auto-detection by adding
localeDetection: false

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#automatic-locale-detection

you can change the locale in _document.jsx

```html
class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    // locale is in ctx.locale

    return { ...initialProps, locale: ctx?.locale || "ar" };
  }

  render = () => (
    <Html
      dir={this.props.locale === "ar" ? "rtl" : "ltr"}
      lang={this.props.locale}
    >
      <Head>
        <link rel="icon" href="" type="image/ico" sizes="16x16"></link>
        <script
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `history.scrollRestoration = "manual"`,
          }}
        />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

Comment: yeah but this doesn't answer my question as I want  en-US and en-UK  to have these as sub-paths in my URL but I want them both to read from en/common.json

Comment: props: {
      collection: collection,
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common"])),
    },

here you can check locale and decide with file you want